# Slim 404 error not being picked up by htaccess file for redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I am not sure I am doing this correct but.

I am triggering a 404 error with Slim 4 when there are no routes present.

```
$app->any('{route:.*}', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
  throw new HttpNotFoundException($request);
});
```

This triggers a 404 error:
[image]

I was hopgin this would then get picked up by my htaccess file and redirect to a customer 404 page.

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

But this is not happening.

Any ideas how I can do this or why this is not working?

Comment: It could be a path issue. To rule this out, please see if you can visit yourdomain.com/404.php in your browser.

Comment: The Apache `ErrorDocument` won't be called if you are triggering the 404 response from your application. The Apache error document is only called if you trigger the 404 in Apache itself.

Comment: Hello @SimonK - Yes this works fine

Comment: The best you can do is to use the same file (ie. `/404.php`) to generate the response from your application.

Comment: @MrWhite - I had this set up as a redirect to 404.php but SEO wise it doesn't like it as it then returns 200      $renderer = new PhpRenderer(__DIR__);
  return $renderer->render($response, "404.php", $args);}

Comment: This will not work as expected, because apache has already delegated the request to php and php throws that exception. So apache is not responsible for this kind of error.  You don't need a htaccess file for this. Instead you may need a Middleware that catches and all HttpNotFoundExceptions and renders a response, or you use the Slim ErrorMiddleware.